# How to override the product stock status behaviour based on custom product attribute

Tags: magento2

Am using Magento2 CE 2.1.10

A custom boolean attribute (global scope) has been added, attribute code "custom_force_on_web" with default value of false.

Desired outcome is that an out of stock product (either inventory quantity is zero and/or its' status is set to "Out of Stock") be visible in its parent category page (frontend) and any category search filters results if
"custom_force_on_web" is true for a given product.

By "category search filters" I'm referring to what you see under
"Shopping Options" when on the frontend category page.

Native Magento2 behaviour is to exclude "Out of Stock" products in category page and in any category search.
Native Magento2 does allow to show "Out of Stock" products but only as a global yes/no option for all products.
What I need is the ability to apply this at/on the product level, via the custom attribute.

This is required by my employers' customer, there's no wiggle room.

I have already googled this subject, traced the Catalog, CatalogInventory and CatalogSearch modules, and official Magento2 documentation.

I have discussed this in the official Magento2 irc channel.

Basically no one knows how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try this logic, by default show out of stock = Yes and condition that logic with your custom attribute, like if custom_force_on_web = TRUE then show these products and if NO then remove from collection ?

Comment: That might work, I'll have to discuss with my team lead as it changes the intended logic of the custom attribute.
Also I could trace how the native "show out of stock products" feature works, that will give me something to follow in terms of code implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: Update:  I have this feature 90% working...remaining issue is that the category filter product count excludes ConfigurableProduct products that are out of stock and have the custom "custom_force_on_web" attribute value as true.

FYI I had to add overrides for modules Magento_CatalogInventory, Magento_CatalogSearch as the product stock status "logic" is copy/pasted in several places.